# Can this transformer supply 2000 Watts according to its labeling?

Tags: electrical

I have a 5M voltage transformer, can I use it to my 110V appliance with 2000 watts? Insert is the picture of my transformer

[image: picture of my transformer]

Answer (score 6):

I'd say no its rated 500 watts

Answer (score 0):

If your appliance is 110 volts are you sure that you need to run it through that transformer. Check to see if it can run on 120 volts.